# How to understand Ad serving has been disabled to my appname

Tags: android, admob

I publish my app and wait 3 days and still admob not load ads.

App.class

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-***");
```

layout.xml

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-***" />
```

loadbanner

```
 AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I use latest library.
I delete testids and code, check my code many times, unit and app ids.
I try delete and reinstall.
I create payments
I look up from many sites.(stackowerflow,quora...)

I want to know How can I learn my appname or packname is disable.  App already publish to google play. Is that possible to publish different packagename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two method to do so**

1. Once Ad serving has been disabled for your App.You will get Email from Google Admod which contains the reason why they have disabled it.
2. In case if you don't get such a mail from admob, then you need to test your live app on few devices (More than 2 device so you can be sure about disabling ad.).

   3. You can directly ask admob about status of your ad servie. Additionally, notifications are sent to the email address associated with your AdSense or admob account.

Thanks

Comment: I got detailed email.